# STM32 HAL SPI Clock issues

Tags: stm32, clock, spi, hal

New to using HAL, and I'm having several issues with setting up the SPI.

I'm using SPI 1 on an STM32F429ZGT6.

Here's my setup:

```
SPI_HandleTypeDef SPI_1;

void SPI_INIT(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();
    SPI_1.Instance = SPI1;
    SPI_1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    SPI_1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    SPI_1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    SPI_1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
    SPI_1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
    SPI_1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    SPI_1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    SPI_1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    SPI_1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    SPI_1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;
    HAL_SPI_Init(&SPI_1);
}

static void ConfigGPIOA(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}


static void ConfigGPIOE(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();       
    
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI_CS02_Pin|SPI_CS03_Pin|SPI_CS00_Pin|SPI_CS01_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

Just initializing SPI 1 and configuring GPIO Pins 5, 6 and 7 for SPI1. I set up GPIOE Pins 0, 1, 2 and 3 for a manual chip select, and I'm writing to them for an idle high (initializing them as pullup doesn't seem to work)

Here's my main:

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    GPIOInit();
    SPI_INIT();

    for(spibyte=0; spibyte < 4; spibyte++)
    {
        CS_LOW();
        if(spibyte == 0)
        {
            HAL_SPI_Transmit(&SPI_1, (uint8_t *)0x51, 2, 10);
        }
        if(spibyte >= 1)
        {
            HAL_SPI_Transmit(&SPI_1, (uint8_t *)0xFF, 2, 10);
        }
        _DELAY(TDISCS);
        CS_HIGH();
   }
}
```

GPIOInit() runs both ConfigGPIOA and ConfigGPIOE.

CS_LOW() and CS_HIGH() are macros that just pull the chip select up and down. I've watched the chip select line on the oscilloscope and it does switch.

Project builds and loads onto the board, but the MOSI pin is silent, and putting the scope on the clock pin, the clock line is pulled up once, comes back down, and remains that way.

I will also note that the clock idles low, even though I've clearly set the clock polarity to high on my SPI initiailization.

Is there something I'm missing? I don't understand why the SPI lines are acting this way.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, when asking someone to read your code, at least make it less painful for them to do so, it will increase the chances someone actually reads the question and are able to answer it.

Comment: `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&SPI_1, (uint8_t *)0x51, 2, 10);` means that your data is at adress 0x51 which is unlikely...

Comment: As Guilaume mentioned, you are using this function wrong. Check description of function in User Manual to HAL drivers or go to header file. You need to pass pointer to value or just address with `&` operator. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `(uint8_t *)0x51` means you pass `0x51` as an address of a buffer. You can not just get address of rvalue `0x51`.
2. You've miscalculated the size of the data. You had to use 1 for
   `uint8_t` instead of 2.

So you have to do the following:

```
uint8_t buffer[] = { 0x51 };
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&SPI_1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 10);
```